# What can I do to force LiveCharts to refresh a chart in order to create a realtime chart that shows constant changes

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, livecharts

I am currently using WinForms. I have two Lists of Values (doubles) which I visualize with the NuGet package "LiveCharts". Now to my problem: The list of the values constantly changes as new values are added to both lists with a frequency of up 200 values / second. Right now I am doing this with Random Values. In a loop I add a new random value to each list and remove the value with the index 0. Now I want the chart to update everytime a new value is added to the list, but although I call the method which should do that everytime I change the values, the chart only updates after the loop ended.

This method is called by a button and should add 10 new values. This works, but the chart only updates after the for-loop is finished, although the UpdateChart() method is called everytime.

```
 private void ReloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                
                valueList1.RemoveAt(0);
                AddRandomValueToList1();
                valueList2.RemoveAt(0);
                AddRandomValueToList2();
                UpdateChart();
             }
            
        }
```

This is the UpdateChart() method I use to update the chart Revenue is a class object and contains a value and a DateTime

```
private void UpdateChart()
        {

            series1 = new SeriesCollection();

           // series.Clear();

            double[] values1 = new double[valueList1.Count];
            double[] values2 = new double[valueList2.Count];

            int index = 0;

            foreach(Revenue current in valueList1)
            {
                values1[index] = current.value;
                index++;
            }

            index = 0;

            foreach (Revenue current in valueList2)
            {
                values2[index] = current.value;
                index++;
            }

            series1.Add(new LineSeries()
            {
                Title = "Values1",
                Values = new ChartValues<double>(values1)
            });
            series1.Add(new LineSeries()
            {
                Title = "Values2",
                Values = new ChartValues<double>(values2)
            });

            cartesianChart1.Series = series1;
 
        }
```

I have already tried to add breaks (Thread.Sleep) hoping the chart would refresh, but that did not work. As well as the cartesianChart1.Refresh() method which I called in the for-loop. Also did I disable the animations, but still got not the result I was hoping achieve.

Now I do not know what I can do to force the chart to refresh everytime I change the values of the lists in order to create a realtime chart.

I am grateful for every help

Thanks in advance